# need to get the actual request body content from WebRequest while overriding handleMethodArgumentNotValid method in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, webrequest, exceptionhandler

I want the request body content from WebRequest when I override the below method in my ExceptionHandler which extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

```
protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
    org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, 
    org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers,
    org.springframework.http.HttpStatus status,
    org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest request) { 
/* compiled code */ }
```

I was able to cast WebRequest to ServletWebRequest like this `((ServletWebRequest)request)` and calling `getRequest()` method to return the `HttpServletRequest`.
But I am not able to get the content from `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`, **its giving blank string or 0 bytes**. Please help me on this.

```
ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapperRequest = 
      new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(((ServletWebRequest)request).getRequest());
```